# Do I need to act on "Tomcat6 APR based Apache Tomcat Native library not found"?

Tags: 10.04, configuration, tomcat6

I've installed tomcat6 via apt-get on lucid and I'm getting the following in my Tomcat `catalina.out` on startup:

```
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in    
production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-
sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-    
1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-    
1.6.0.26/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

PS - Why am I getting this on a vanilla tomcat6 install? (from apt-get ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat native library is a native (non-java) library that can improve the performance of Tomcat in some situations.

This is only hint. You can ignore it.

However, if you want to try it you can install it via:

```
sudo apt-get install libtcnative-1
```